Incremental table - adding new events and deleting these older than 180 days
I need to create a table which stores events and some aggregations for the past 180 days from other two tables.
I think materialized view will work perfectly, but it seems I hit some limitations:
Incremental materialized view - workaround to query table more than once
I want to delete the events older than 180 days and to add only the ones from the past day, because querying the data for the past 180 days is processing 15-16 TB for each run.
My plan is to create a view:
CREATE VIEW test_view AS
SELECT 
colA,
colB,
date_column,
count(*)
FROM table a
WHERE date_column >= current_date - 180
GROUP BY colA,
colB,
date_column
UNION ALL
SELECT 
colA,
colB,
date_column,
count(*)
FROM table b
WHERE date_column >= current_date - 180
GROUP BY colA,
colB,
date_column

And then to use it for table 'test_table' which will have the same structure.
Will this plan work out:

DELETE * FROM test_table
WHERE date_column < current_date - 180;

INSERT INTO test_table
SELECT * FROM test_view
WHERE date_column = current_date - 1;

Or this way the view will query all 180 days and everything will be pointless?

Hi - why not try it and see what happens?

I was wondering if this is a good approach at all or I'm missing something?

If it works and is performant then it's a good approach

Instead of a view, try to create a dedicated table test_table to store your aggregated data then schedule a job to run daily:
DELETE FROM test_table WHERE date_column < current_date - 180

Instead of querying all 180 days in the view, directly insert the data for the past day from the base tables:
INSERT INTO test_table (colA, colB, date_column, count)
SELECT colA, colB, date_column, count(*) 
FROM table_a
WHERE date_column = current_date - 1
GROUP BY colA, colB, date_column
UNION ALL
SELECT colA, colB, date_column, count(*) 
FROM table_b
WHERE date_column = current_date - 1
GROUP BY colA, colB, date_column;

